# Runnable Skipped Android AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I would like to say thanks first to you all..

I have made a code to generate sprite by using Runnable.
But it only executes the last runnable that I wrote.

Here's the code:

```
public class LevellingManager {

// ======================== //
// ======================== //
// THE PATH METHOD              //
// ======================== //
// ======================== //  
public static void path() {
    currType = Leveling2.TYPE_DIGGER;
    mHandler.post(mStartDigger);
    // === NOT EXECUTED === //
    generateSprite(Leveling2.TYPE_ROCK, 10, 2000, 2000, LevellingManager.EASY);
    // === EXECUTED === //
    generateSprite(Leveling2.TYPE_WORM, 8, 3000, 1000, LevellingManager.HARD);
}
```

The **generateSprite()** method

```
    public static void generateSprite(int type, int nSprts, int delayPerSprt,
        int delayPerBtch, int[] difficulty) {
    currType = type;

    switch (type) {
    case Leveling2.TYPE_ROCK:
        System.out.println("Awalnya : " + GameResources2.lastIndexRock);

        // ---- Set Generate Data ---- //
        currIndex = 1 + GameResources2.lastIndexRock;
        currList= GameResources2.listRockToBeAdded;
        currLastIndex = GameResources2.lastIndexRock;
        currMaxCpcty= GameResources2.MAX_ROCK;

        // --- Method to Set the position, speed & delay per sprite ---- //
        set(nSprts, delayPerBtch, delayPerSprt, difficulty);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mStartRock, currDelay);

        GameResources2.lastIndexRock = currLastIndex;

        break;

    case Leveling2.TYPE_WORM:
        // ---- Set Generate Data ---- //
        currIndex = 1 + GameResources2.lastIndexWorm;
        currList=GameResources2.listWormToBeAdded;
        currLastIndex = GameResources2.lastIndexWorm;
        currMaxCpcty = GameResources2.MAX_WORM;

        // --- Method to Set the position, speed & delay per sprite ---- //
        set(nSprts, delayPerBtch, delayPerSprite, difficulty);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mStartWorm, currDelay);

        GameResources2.lastIndexWorm = currLastIndex;
        break;      
    }
}
```

Here comes the **Runnable** code:

```
    public static Runnable mStartRock = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        installAttach(this);
    }
};
public  static Runnable mStartWorm = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        installAttach(this);
    }
};
```

And here is a method that will be executed inside the Runnable.
**installAttach()** method:

```
    private static void installAttach(Runnable r) {

    System.out.println("Lewat sini, type : " + currType);

    currSpriteGen = currList.get(currIndex);

    currSpriteGen
            .registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(
                    new MoveModifier(currSpeed,
                            currSpriteGen.getX(),
                            currSpriteGen.getX(),
                            GameResources2.CAMERA_HEIGHT,
                            GameResources2.POSITION_DIGGER_HEIGHT)));

    currSpriteGen.setVisible(true);

    if (currSpriteGen.getParent() == null)
        GameResources2.scene.attachChild(currSpriteGen);
    else
        currLastIndex = currIndex;

    switchLastIndex();

    if (currIndex == currMaxCpcty - 1) {
        currNSprts = currNSprts - currIndex;
        currIndex = -1;
    }

    System.out.println("Index : " + currIndex);
    System.out.println("Max index : " + currMaxCpcty);

    ++currIndex;

    // --- For looping ---//
    if (currIndex < currNSprts) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(r, currDelay);
    }
}
```

So when I call the **LevellingManager.path()** method at onLoadScene(),
only the last generate method that executed.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a place for only one Runnable. I believe I have a workaround for that. Create a class RunnableBatch whose instance will contain an array of Runnables. It will have a method `add(Runnable r)` that will

1) add the Runnable to the array and

2) create a new Runnable that will contain something like `for (Runnable r : runnableArray) {r.run();}`